# Password algorithm to be integrated on a website

Tags: encryption, web-application, algorithm

I have recently started a project to code a secure password protection algorithm to be used on both computers and mobile devices. As I have never done anything like it before, I am a bit unsure of where to start. This code needs to be extremely secure, but also flexible on the front end. I am familiar with Java, C, and Ruby. Any ideas from people who have done similar projects?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to create a new encryption algorithm for password storage or trying to implement a design that will store passwords securely using current best practices/algorithms?  The first option will get you a lot of "Don't do it yourself!!!" responses, while the second might get meaningful recommendations.

Comment: If you are looking to implement a design to store passwords securely and are familiar with Ruby.  I would checkout Devise (commonly used in rails applications) at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise to see how they implement it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a *really* good idea to not do this yourself; it's easy to mess up if you don't know what you're doing.

The short of it is that you want to hash your passwords with a slow algorithm using a per-user salt.  I won't go into much detail, because there are [plenty](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/) [of](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) [resources](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/are-there-more-modern-password-hashing-methods-than-bcrypt-and-scrypt), here and across the web, talking about which hashing function to use, how to store salts, why you need to do these things, etc.

The frontend is completely irrelevant; you just take in user input and pass it to your password-checking function.